# Как добавить условие при связях

Tags: yii2

Есть класс Price он привязан к классу Product, в моделе Product. Следующим образом

```
public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);

    }
```

в дальнейшем вызывается так $price = $model->price; Появилась нобходимость также делать выборку по одному условию в таблице price есть столбец countryid, там содержатся id стран есть таблица country с информацией о странах. Путем хитрых танцев с бубном я получаю id страны с которой заходит пользователь. Но вот как мне отобрать теперь по столбцу countryid ума не приложу подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из мануала:

```
$model->getPrice()
->where(['countryid' => $countryid])
->all();
```